# Excel VBA returning values to multiple cells from XML web query

Tags: xml, excel, excel-2007, xml-import, vba

I have XML data on the web. Those are prices and price data of an in game item:

https://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?regionlimit=10000002&typeid=34

Invoke of function to get **SINGLE** value (for example highest buy order):

```
     A       B
1 ItemID  buy/max
2  34      =ImportXML("https:// ... &typeid=34", "//buy/max")
3  35
```

Function looks like:

```
Function ImportXML(url As String, query As String)

Dim document    As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim http        As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

http.Open "GET", url, False
http.send

Set document = http.responseXML

ImportXML = document.SelectSingleNode(query).nodeTypedValue

End Function
```

It's OK for one value. If I got 500 items, getting data is extremely long.
To populate multiple cells (in this case only two) we need to modify input link by adding *&typeid=35*:

https://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?regionlimit=10000002&typeid=34&typeid=35

With that link I can get two values into *MsgBox*. But I need to work on that data so I need that in cell *B3*.
Now code looks like this:

```
Function ImportXML(url As String, query As String)

Dim document    As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim http        As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

http.Open "GET", url, False
http.send

Set document = http.responseXML

Dim R As Integer
Dim C As Integer
R = ActiveCell.Row                         '<- these variables are for changing'
C = ActiveCell.Column                      '<- output cell'

Set xmlNodeList = document.SelectNodes(query)
For Each xmlNode In xmlNodeList
    Cells(R, C) = xmlNode.nodeTypedValue   '<- THIS LINE CAUSE AN ERROR'
    'MsgBox xmlNode.nodeTypedValue          <- if that line is active I got correct result'
    R = R + 1                                 'but in MsgBox' 
Next xmlNode

End Function
```

When I'm trying to write data from query into cells there is an problem.
What I'm trying to achieve is **similar behaviour to *ImportXML*** function from ***Google Sheets web service***.
I don't have Excel 2013 so I can not use *WEBSERVICE* function or *FILTERXML* and *XPath*.
I have never code in VBA.
If You can put here the final code I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

For your line giving the error:

```
Cells(R, C) = xmlNode.nodeTypedValue
```

Can you try this instead:

```
Cells(R, C).Value = CStr(xmlNode.nodeTypedValue)
```